# Can't create NSMutableAttributedString from NSTextAttachment

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to use the initializator of `NSMutableAttributedString`:

```
NSMutableAttributedString(attachment: NSTextAttachment())
```

but I get an error:

> Argument labels '`(attachment:)`' does not match any available overloads.

Answer (score 0):

You should first create an `NSAttributedString` with an attachment and then initialize a mutable string from it:

```
let attrString = NSAttributedString(attachment: textAttachment)
let mutableAttrString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attrString)
```

Comment: Can you explain why? NSMutableAttributedString shows that there is initializer with attachment...